# Python: Pandas to latex - Issues with the backslash

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df` for which I want to rename the columns to:

$\beta_0$, $\beta_{t-1}$ ...

such that I get the appropriate latex input. I tried the following:

```
df.columns = ['$ \\beta_0 $', ' $\\beta_{t-1} $', '$ \\beta_{t-2} $', '$ \\beta_{t-3} $']
```

I also tried `r' $ \beta_0$'` for intansce ... and when I do `print df.to_latex()` I get:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
{} & \$ \textbackslashbeta\_0 \$ &  \$\textbackslashbeta\_\{t-1\} \$ & \$ \textbackslashbeta\_\{t-2\} \$ & \$ \textbackslashbeta\_\{t-3\} \$ \\
\midrule
```

Why do the `\textbackslash` keeps showing up? I thought that `\\` or `r` would have solve this issue...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note**: starting with pandas 2.0, the default for `escape` has change to `False`, so there is no longer a need to set it manually.

You can use the `escape=False` option of [`to_latex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html):

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['$ \\beta $', r'$ \gamma $'])

In [12]: print(df.to_latex())
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  \$ \textbackslashbeta \$ &  \$ \textbackslashgamma \$ \\
\midrule
0 &          1 &           2 \\
1 &          3 &           4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

In [13]: print(df.to_latex(escape=False))
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  $ \beta $ &  $ \gamma $ \\
\midrule
0 &          1 &           2 \\
1 &          3 &           4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the `Escape=False` option.

Comment: After mining for 30 minutes here, I found this pearl. Thank you very much.

Comment: Stumbled about the same issue in my jupyter notebook. Hat the to_latex call as my last expression. Wrapping the expression in a print() gave the expected behavior. Even without the escape flag set.

Comment: That's because the default value of the `escape` keyword changed, so nowadays you indeed no longer need to specify it manually. Updated the answer to mention that.